# file upload without activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you handle file upload in rail without attaching them to active record ?
I just want to write the files to the disk.

Thanks,

Comment: Try this http://easyrails.herokuapp.com/blogs/5/upload-file-in-rails-without-model-creation

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need then the most simple example would be this:

The controller:

```
  class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
    name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
    path = File.join("public", "images", "upload", name)
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload][:file].read) }
    flash[:notice] = "File uploaded"
    redirect_to "/upload/new"
  end
end
```

The view:

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => [key, " message"], :id => "notice_#{key}" %>
<% end %>
<% form_tag '/upload/create', { :multipart => true } do %>
    <p>
    <%= file_field_tag 'upload[file]' %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This would let you upload any file without any checks or validations which in my opinion isn't that usefull.

If I would do it myself then I would use something like [validatable gem](http://validatable.rubyforge.org/) or [tableless gem](http://github.com/kennethkalmer/activerecord-tableless-models) just tableless is not supported anymore. These gems would allow you to validate what you're uploading to make it more sane.

Comment: Just make sure to use <%= form_tag ... %> in rails 3.

Comment: to be consistent shouldn't you use `File.join("public", "images", "upload")` to create `directory`?

Comment: Sure, that's a good tip. Wrote this really long time ago :) Don't think I knew how to do that at the time:) Just used examples when coding so in one line I use it :)) On the other I don't. Updating now.

Answer (score 6):

You can just move the temporary file to destiny path using FileUtils

```
tmp = params[:my_file_field].tempfile
destiny_file = File.join('public', 'uploads', params[:my_file_field].original_filename)
FileUtils.move tmp.path, destiny_file
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Tempfile` documentation shows an example that's equivalent to Rytis's code, which is fine most of the time. But when you call `tempfile.read`, Ruby is reading the whole file as a single chunk into memory, which is sub-optimal.

However, `FileUtils` provides a `copy_stream` method, and `IO`, at least in Ruby 2.0, provides a [`copy_stream`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-copy_stream) implementation that handles writing directly to a filepath (`FileUtils.copy_stream` requires File-like objects on both sides, or so say the docs).

In my case, I was initiating a large multi-file upload via AJAX, and wanted to avoid reading the whole file(s) into Ruby's memory before writing to disk.

In the example below, `params[:files]` is an `Array` of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` instances, and `local_filepath` is a string pointing to a non-existing file in an existing directory. For brevity, I'll assume I'm only uploading one file:

```
IO.copy_stream(params[:files][0].tempfile, local_filepath)
```

The `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` instance has a `.tempfile` field that's just a regular `Tempfile` instance.

I'm not actually sure that Ruby still isn't reading the whole file into memory—I didn't benchmark anything—but it's a lot more possible than it is with the `localfile.write(tempfile.read)` syntax.

**tl;dr**: `IO.copy_stream(your_tempfile, your_disk_filepath)` is more concise, if not faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Rails plugin [Attachment_fu](http://wiki.github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu) to handle file uploads. It allows you to save uploads to the file system instead of the database.