# Upload Image in Rails Without Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to upload Image in rails without use Model.
I just want to use simple php to upload.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you using Ruby on Rails or are you using PHP? What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you will run all your server code in Ruby, **not** PHP. To create a file upload do the following:

```
> rails g controller uploader

# app/controller/uploader_controller.rb

def create
  @file = params[:file]
end


# app/views/uploader/new.html.erb

<%= form_tag(uploader_path, multipart: true) do |form| %>
  <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Sylvestre I will try soon .

Answer (score -1):

Upload file in rails without model creation

http://easyrails.herokuapp.com/blogs/5/upload-file-in-rails-without-model-creation

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: @MarkDavies Link expired. Here is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676195/file-upload-without-activerecord