# Image upload in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i need to upload one image and send that into one api,here not using the database.i have used
this [file upload without activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676195/file-upload-without) activerecord but not   working.
it gives the error with **orginal_filename**? this is what i am getting when i use this

```
file_param = params[:name]
file_name = file_param.original_filename  
NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename' for "C:\\fakepath\\logo-big.png":String):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it a good idea to use gem `carrierwave`. Here is an awesome [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads). Check it out.

**Update**

if your `view` something like this: `<%= file_field_tag 'upload[file]' %>`

change your controller code to this:

```
file_name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
```

Comment: yes, but this http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads using the models, in my app, not using the database, just take one file from directory and send to one api, through URL with RestClient::Resource

Comment: I have updated answer check it out. If it's not worked please provide you `view` code. Thanks.

Comment: VIEW code
<%= form_tag '/create', :method => :post, :multipart => true   do  %>
            
   <%= file_field_tag 'upload[file]' %>               
  <%= submit_tag "Upload",  :class => "photo_up btn btn-success" %> 
 <%end%>

CONTROLLER code
file_name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
    show_url = "........."
    resource = RestClient::Resource.new show_url, :user => "admin",:password => "admin"
    resource.post  :file => File.new(file_name, 'rb'),:multipart => true
now getting error  Errno::ENOENT in PersonalityController#create
 No such file or directory - images.jpg

Comment: okay, could you tell me what actually you wanna do with this file. Are you wanna read this file and then write it to a file of your application directory?

Comment: i have tried one way and i got that, when i use like this file_param = params[:upload]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while uploading images.

I have revised c://fackpath/filename.* in backend.

Just add this into your form to fix the issue:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```